# Getting invalid username and password in SQL loader command

Tags: oracle, sql-loader

```
sqlldr system/(giving my password) control='E:\sqlloader\load_test.ctl'
```

But it throws an error

```
SQL*Loader-128: unable to begin a session

ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied
```

Comment: Why don't you use an ordinary user rather than `system` which's intended to be used for administrational purposes.

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan Could you suggest me other users which don't require a password

Answer (score 0):

That's because you provided **invalid password**.

This is what I literally did; `xxx` certainly isn't `system`'s password:

```
c:\Temp>sqlldr system/xxx control=a.ctl

SQL*Loader: Release 11.2.0.2.0 - Production on Pet Lis 29 20:17:58 2021

Copyright (c) 1982, 2009, Oracle and/or its affiliates.  All rights reserved.

SQL*Loader-128: unable to begin a session
ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied
```

But, if I provide a valid password (which I won't reveal, though), it *works*:

```
c:\Temp>sqlldr system/valid_password control=a.ctl

SQL*Loader: Release 11.2.0.2.0 - Production on Pet Lis 29 20:18:11 2021
<snip>
```

---

Also, just as Barbaros told you, don't use `system` (nor `sys`) for your own amusement. Create any other user and use its schema for your playground. Here's how (on my 11gXE database): connect as `sys`:

```
c:\Temp>sqlplus sys as sysdba

SQL*Plus: Release 11.2.0.2.0 Production on Pet Lis 29 20:21:05 2021

Copyright (c) 1982, 2014, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Enter password:

Connected to:
Oracle Database 11g Express Edition Release 11.2.0.2.0 - 64bit Production
```

Check which tablespaces you have:

```
SQL> select tablespace_name from dba_tablespaces;

TABLESPACE_NAME
------------------------------
SYSTEM
SYSAUX
UNDOTBS1
TEMP
USERS
```

Create user:

```
SQL> create user vicky
  2  identified by barba              --> this is the password
  3  default tablespace users
  4  temporary tablespace temp
  5  quota unlimited on users;

User created.
```

Grant some privileges; later, grant others as you need them:

```
SQL> grant create session, create table to vicky;

Grant succeeded.
```

Let's try it:

```
SQL> connect vicky/barba
Connected.
SQL> create table test as select 1 id, sysdate datum from dual;

Table created.

SQL> select * From test;

        ID DATUM
---------- --------
         1 29.10.21

SQL>
```

Comment: Thanks I did the same steps but when I am giving connect vicky/tiger124 it is again throwing error username/password incorrect logon denied. I did the same what you have done